# chain rule of a second derivative

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Suppose I have the following function where
$$z=\omega(\zeta)=\frac{1}{\zeta}$$ and also,
$$\phi(\zeta) = \zeta^{-1}+2\zeta$$
By using chain rule, I can get the first-derivative of $\phi(z)$. Notice that I want now $\phi$ as a function of $z$. Thus,
$$\phi'(z)=\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}\frac{d\zeta}{dz}=\frac{\phi'(\zeta)}{\omega'(\zeta)}$$
where, 
$$\omega'(\zeta) = \frac{d\omega(\zeta)}{d\zeta}=\frac{dz}{d\zeta}$$

My question is, how can we get the second-derivative of $\phi(z)$, i.e. $\phi''(z)$? By using chain rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have $\phi'(z)$, so just differentiate it using the product and chain rules:

$$\phi''(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}\right)\frac{d\zeta}{dz} + \frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{d\zeta}{dz}\right) = \frac{d^2\phi}{d\zeta^2}\left(\frac{d\zeta}{dz}\right)^2+\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}\frac{d^2\zeta}{dz^2}.$$

Notice that nothing we've done uses the form of your functions, so this holds in full generality. In your special case, you could also just substitute everything into get $\phi$ in terms of $z$ directly, then differentiate that twice.

Comment: Thanks @user3482749! I am actually trying to avoid direct substitution but rather go with this implicitly through chain rule.

Comment: I still don't  understand how to get the first part in the last expression, i.e. $\frac{d^2\phi}{d\zeta^2}\left(\frac{d\zeta}{dz}\right)^2$

Comment: Sure: $\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}\right) = \frac{d^2\phi}{d\zeta^2}\frac{d\zeta}{dz}$ by the chain rule (applied to the function $\frac{d\phi}{d\zeta}$), then it's multiplied by $\frac{d\zeta}{dz}$, so I've grouped the two copies of $\frac{d\zeta}{dz}$ together.